# Trouble getting nth character of a string

Tags: c, string, pointers, indexing, types

In my program, I am making a `char line[MAXLINE]` and then using it in:

```
fgets(line, sizeof line, f);
```

I can then print this line with

```
printf("%s\n",line);
```

However, trying something like

```
printf("%s\n",line[10]);
```

warns me that `line[10]` is of type `int`, and something like

```
printf("%s\n",line + 10);
```

prints from character 10 onwards.

how can I just get the *n*th character of this string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the *n*th character like so:

```
char ch = line[10];
```

But you can't print it as a string, because it's *not* a string. Print it as a character:

```
printf("%c\n", line[10]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing when you use %s in the format string in printf is printing the null-terminated string starting from the the provided pointer.

line+10 is the pointer to the 11th character in the string so it prints everything it finds in memory until it encounters /0 (null) character.

To print a single character you have to use %c in the format string.

```
printf("%c",line+10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%s\n",line + 10);  // %s expects a char *
```

Instead print like this -

```
printf("%c\n",line + 10);
```

> how can I just get the nth character of this string?

With `strlen()` function from `<string.h>` you can get length of string. Thus easily you can get the **nth** character. of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The below will also work as a string in C is a `char` pointer to the first character. (Strings are terminated in memory with the character `\0`, that's how programs know where they end.)

`line` is a pointer to the first character and it can be advanced to the 10th character, as below (we have to advance it by 9, as no advance points to the first character).

`*` dereferences the pointer to get the actual value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char line[] = "abcdefghijkl";
    printf("%c\n", *(line+9));

    return 0;
}
```